# Why are addresses of pointers to a WaitGroup different in this golang snippet?

Tags: go

Code snippet on [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/XKCjSgG62m)

I am printing the pointer address for `sync.WaitGroup` and they are all different. Why?

```
func Run() *sync.WaitGroup {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        fmt.Printf("goroutine %p\n", &wg)

        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("wokeup")
    }()

    fmt.Printf("returning %p\n", &wg)
    return &wg
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(3)
    wg := Run()

    fmt.Printf("     main %p\n", &wg)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Typical output shows that the address is diff between that inside the function `Run` and `main`. I'd expect that to be the same, n'est-ce pas ?

```
returning 0xc0840045c0
     main 0xc084000038
goroutine 0xc0840045c0
wokeup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync"
import "time"
import "runtime"

func Run() *sync.WaitGroup {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        fmt.Printf("goroutine %p\n", &wg)
        fmt.Println("sleep for 5s")
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("wokeup")
    }()
    fmt.Printf("returning %p\n", &wg)
    return &wg
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(3)
    wg := Run()
    fmt.Printf("     main %p\n", wg)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Output:

```
returning 0x1052e2c0
     main 0x1052e2c0
goroutine 0x1052e2c0
sleep for 5s
```

Change

```
fmt.Printf("     main %p\n", &wg)
```

to

```
fmt.Printf("     main %p\n", wg)
```

In `main`, the variable `wg` contains the address you want. You are printing the address of the variable that contains the address.

Comment: After ruminating over this, I think I am going to annotate my variable so that I know they are pointers. e.g. `p_wg`

Comment: @canadadry Do as you like, but usually you have types for this. If you're unsure what type a variable has, try explicitly declaring it with *var foo \*Type* or something to that effect.

Comment: Thanks @FUZxxl that's another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you notice, the "returning" print statement and the "goroutine" print statement give the same address. Your "main" print is what is off. Look at the line:

```
fmt.Printf("     main %p\n", &wg)
```

What do you notice? You're printing `&wg`, the address of whatever `wg` is assigned to.

Now look at the return value of your `Run()` function, you're returning `&wg`. A pointer to your first declaration of `wg` as a variable.

So basically your "main" print is printing the the address of the `wg` pointer address rather than the pointer address itself... hope that makes sense...

But yeah, changing the line in "main" to

```
fmt.Printf("     main %p\n", wg)
```

should work.